# Grails 3 Url Mappings

Tags: grails

How does one create a default, match all pattern?

For Ex:

```
"/"(controller: "home", action: "index")
"401"(controller: "error", action: "unauthorized")
"404"(controller: "error", action: "nF")
"500"(controller: "error", action: "err")
```

When the user hits an application http://myapp.com/appName/ , the / mapping gets invoked. How do we add a pattern so that even the url http://myapp.com/appName (without the fordward slash) gets invoked?

I have tried to do the following so far:

```
""(controller: "home", action: "index")
" "(controller: "home", action: "index")
"*"(controller: "home", action: "index")
"*/**"(controller: "home", action: "index")
any(controller: "home", action: "index")
```

But all result in several errors, out of which, some include:

```
MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.grails.web.mapping.DefaultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder.any() is applicable for argument types:
No signature of method: org.grails.web.mapping.DefaultUrlMappingEvaluator$UrlMappingBuilder.*/**() is applicable for argument types:
```

Comment: @vahid the url mappings are a grails groovy class, that can be defined (as I have done above) are you saying that the spring security plugin is required to make this work?

Comment: apologies thought it was security related

Comment: no worries. I appreciate the feedback regardless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

patterns should always begin with a forward slash:

```
 "/**"(controller: "home", action: "index")
```